# How to use UUID and cookies without interfering with shopify's code?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, shopify

I need a UUID for google analytics session unification. I read that I need to use UUID and cookies. Seems simple enough, but will that interfere with shopify's code (the cookies they use themselves)?

Could I just use

```
document.cookie = Math.random()
ga('set', 'userId', document.cookie; // Set the user ID using signed-in user_id.
```

Comment: `document.cookie` is an API, not "a real string."  When you READ its value, you get a list of all cookies.  But, when you ASSIGN a value, you actually only affect one cookie, =and= "you must do it in just the 'right' way."  Given that you are doing this for a very specific purpose ("Google analytics session unification"), I would start by "Googling, specifically, THAT."  Don't waste your time re-doing something that somebody else already wasted THEIR time on, given that they were kind-enough to share with you "what actually worked."

Comment: I did google it actually but the only information I could find was about people using it for registered users, I need to do it for unregistered users and I'm not that great of a programmer so I'm kind of stuck. Every other part is well documented except for this it seems. Also could you be a bit more specific about how I should write the code to use the cookie in it.

Comment: At this point, I'd suggest that you open a new browser window or tab, break out of this particular site, and do a web-search.  "Registered vs. unregistered" users must surely be "a Google-API issue," not a true matter of the underlying JavaScript technology.  And, "I'd bet dishrags to donuts" that someone out there has dealt with this specific thing.  (Who knows ... maybe they posted a complete solution to GitHub.)  Basically, these days, as soon as you begin to suspect that 'surely, someone ELSE has done this,' you should not only 'presume that indeed they did,' and STOP AND GO FIND IT.

Comment: Dude I'm posting here cause I already googled everything I could come up with and nothing shows up. It's a lot quicker to make a search than to make a post. Just try it yourself, nothing comes up https://www.google.ca/search?q=Registered+vs.+unregistered&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=3ltsV5_NJMuXesnNu8AB#q=Registered+vs.+unregistered+analytics+session+ID+unification

Comment: I see 3,760 results.  However, aye, this be your problem not mine.  Good day to thee.

Comment: yeah and those 3 000 results are just as useless as your posts

Comment: @DanyM.. You can reach out to google support team. They have very good Shopify handling teams. They'll guide you better than anyone.

Comment: You shouldn't use userId for unregistered users, a) because the point is that  the user is identified by the server (so he is recongized across devices independently from the Cookie) and b) because this would most likely violate Google's TOS (which stipulate that all persistent storage for the userid must be deleted when a user logs out).

Comment: What do you suggest I do Eike? I've been trying to fix my google analytics tracking shopify for days and even hired 2 people on upwork and they haven't been able to fix it. I would gladly spend money to get this fixed

Comment: You cannot do session unification without a identifier set by the server, since you need a reliabe mechanism to recognize recurring users; if you do it via cookies you are replicating the mechanism that Google Analytics uses anyway (clientid is stored in cookies and used to aggregate pageviews into sessions). Also, and I'm sorry I don't know how to say this without sounding like a prick, somebody with less than basic programming skills should not try to make changes to a system into which people enter personal data.

Comment: I agree. I'm just desperate. Nothing I try or no one I hire has been able to fix it.